# collection_select from entities with specific attibute

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have the following collection_select tag:

```
<%=collection_select(:post, :applicant_id, Room.all, :room_number, :room_number, {selected: @applicant.room_number}, { :onchange=>"window.location='#{room_select_path(@applicant.id)}?room_number=' + this.value"})%>
```

Currently, it displays all room entities available.

What I want to do is to display all room entities with the attribute :room_type.

Comment: You want to display all room entities base on :room_type value or you have another dropdown to select :room_type and you want to display rooms base on that dropdown value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%=collection_select(:post, :applicant_id, Room.where(room_type: "your_type_value"), :room_number, :room_number, {selected: @applicant.room_number}, { :onchange=>"window.location='#{room_select_path(@applicant.id)}?room_number=' + this.value"})%>
```